# Free software to visualize streamed audio and video timestamps, keyframes etc. to identify cause of audio video sync issues?

Tags: linux, video, video-editing, streaming, synchronization

**Purpose:** I store a streamed meeting video on disk. I need to analyze the video to see which parts have an audio-video lag and also need to see other details of the video like codec, keyframes or any other data that helps identify the cause of audio-video sync issues.

**Operating system:** Linux and/or MacOS.

**Tools I've searched:** Transcription software that displays video metadata, tools specifically meant to fix audio video sync issues and FFPROBE.